# Populating an Android ListView with multiple data sources (using Loaders)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, listadapter, android-cursorloader

I've three database tables: `Stacks`, `Dates` and `Z`, where `Stacks` is my main table, and `Dates` and `Z` are 'child' tables, with a foreign key column, linking to the primary key column of `Stacks`. (Forgive my terminology, I can present the schema if needed.)

I will henceforth only refer to `Stacks` and `Dates`, to reduce the complexity of my explanation, but in case it is relevant, `Z` will be used in exactly the same way as `Dates`.

In a typical `ListFragment`, I construct a `ListView` using the implementation discussed on the `LoaderManager` [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) - creating an empty adapter, then swapping the `Cursor` out when my query has finished(query in `onCreateLoader()` and swap in `onLoadFinished()`).

I query against the `Stacks` table (using the URI, as my DB is fronted by a `Content Provider` implemented using the `Simple Content Provider` [library](https://github.com/mitmel/SimpleContentProvider)), as the values I want to bind to each list item in `getView()` in the adapter, are mostly found here, and this works fine.

However, I also wish to bind some values from the `Dates` table, though I'm unsure how to do this. Prior to using loaders, I would create a new `SQLiteOpenHelper` in the adapter, and access the secondary items directly in the getView() method, i.e. return `Cursor`s from the `Dates` table. This was slow, and I'm pretty sure it was a bad idea in hindsight :P

**Is there a standard way to implement this, filling a list view using multiple sources of data (ideally using Loaders)?**

Edit:

- The `Dates` table may have multiple records (with different values)
  for each associated `Stack`.
- I have one ContentProvider which provides access to all three tables, depending on URI
- I'm happy to use multiple loaders also, as I suspect I'll have to do anyway as I need to display other information in the fragment not associated with the content in the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this on a per row basis you basically have two alternatives:

1. Do everything up front in your `ContentProvider`, for example by using subqueries or a more complex query.
2. Do the query async in `getView()` of your `Adapter`. This is similar to how loading remote images work.

Both methods have their strengths. #1 is probably simpler but may not be fast enough if you have a lot of items in your list. #2 is fast as you will only query the relevant dates, however canceling (or avoid making) queries when scrolling can be a pain.

Loaders doesn't make sense when you have to do a unknown number of loads.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll explore these over the next few days

Comment: I've decided on the second option, and then cache the results so cancelling is unnecessary, as will be requerying. Thanks!